# How to add permissions to user to channel by command? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How to give permissions to a specific channel by command? Sorry, I’m new at discord.js so any help would be appreciated.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
 name: 'addrole',
 run: async (bot, message, args) => {
  //!addrole @user RoleName
  let rMember =
   message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) ||
   message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
  if (!rMember) return message.reply("Couldn't find that user, yo.");
  let role = args.join(' ').slice(22);
  if (!role) return message.reply('Specify a role!');
  let gRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === role);
  if (!gRole) return message.reply("Couldn't find that role.");

  if (rMember.roles.has(gRole.id));
  await rMember.addRole(gRole.id);

  try {
   const oofas = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('something')
    .setColor(`#000000`)
    .setDescription(`Congrats, you have been given the role ${gRole.name}`);
   await rMember.send(oofas);
  } catch (e) {
   message.channel.send(
    `Congrats, you have been given the role ${gRole.name}. We tried to DM `
   );
  }
 },
};
```

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#checking-member-permissions look in the channel overwites section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GuildChannel.updateOverwrites()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite) to update the permissions on a channel.

> ```js
> // Update or Create permission overwrites for a message author
> message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
>  SEND_MESSAGES: false
> })
>   .then(channel => console.log(channel.permissionOverwrites.get(message.author.id)))
>   .catch(console.error);
> ```

(From example in the `discord.js` docs)

Using this function, you can provide a `User` or `Role` `Object` or `ID` of which to update permissions (in your case, you can use `gRole`).

Then, you can list the permissions to update followed by `true`, to allow, or `false`, to reject.

[Here is a full list of permission flags you can use](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)

Answer (score 1):

This method is outdated and doesn't work on V13+ the new way is doing this:

```
channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(role, {SEND_MESSAGES: true }

channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(member, {SEND_MESSAGES: true }
```